# AWS Lambda Layer how to compress folder instead of contents of folder in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, zip, archive

I have this terraform code for my lambda and lambda layer:

```
#lambda
resource "aws_lambda_function" "sql_automation_lambda" {
  function_name    = "${var.project_name}${var.environment}-NAME"
  handler          = "lambda_handler.lambda_handler"
  role             = IAM_ROLE
  runtime          = "python3.9"
  filename         = PATH
  layers           = [aws_lambda_layer_version.my_layer.arn]
}

# create zip file from requirements.txt. Triggers only when the file is updated
resource "null_resource" "lambda_layer" {
  triggers = {
    requirements = filesha1("${path.module}/files/requirements.txt")
  }
  # the command to install python and dependencies to the machine and zips

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "python3 -m pip install -r ${"${path.module}/files/requirements.txt"} -t ${path.module}/python"
  }
}

#Create zip file
data "archive_file" "layer" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "${path.module}/python"
  output_path = "${path.module}/python.zip"
  depends_on  = [null_resource.lambda_layer]
}

resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "my_layer" {
  layer_name          = "python"
  filename            = data.archive_file.layer.output_path
  source_code_hash    = data.archive_file.layer.output_base64sha256
  compatible_runtimes = ["python3.11", "python3.10", "python3.8", "python3.9", "python3.7"]
}
```

Everything gets created without issue but when i test the lambda I get the error “[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module […] No module named […] “

I know how to fix the error - make sure I have my lambda layer set up so that everything is in one directory called “python” - I have created a layer manually, where I just right clicked my python folder and clicked compress and then uploaded this as the lambda layer and this works.

What seems to be happening when I create it via terraform is that I think the contents of my python directory are getting zipped rather than the folder itself. Because when I go to the lambda and download it - it will download as python-[RANDOM_STRING].zip which is expected as this is related to aws layer versioning.

But when I unzip it the directory will also be called “python-[RANDOM_STRING]” rather than just python. And because of this my lambda isn’t working as it is no longer called just “python”

If I go back to my manually made lambda layer, it will download as “python-[RANDOM_STRING].zip” and when I unzip it I get the “python” directory as expected and is what i want.

So basically on this screenshot you can see that when i unzip my manually made compress-testing layer, the folder within that is "python". Where as the one made from terraform is just getting unzipped as the same layer name
[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this in my terraform code?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this by moving the "python" folder into another folder, and then zipping the new folder. I create the python folder within a "layer" folder now and zip this. My code is now:

```
# create zip file from requirements.txt. Triggers only when the file is updated
resource "null_resource" "lambda_layer" {
  triggers = {
    requirements = filesha1("${path.module}/files/requirements.txt")
  }
  # the command to install python and dependencies to the machine and zips

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "python3 -m pip install -r ${"${path.module}/files/requirements.txt"} -t ${path.module}/layer/python"
  }
}

#Create zip file
data "archive_file" "layer" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "${path.module}/layer"
  output_path = "${path.module}/python.zip"
  depends_on  = [null_resource.lambda_layer]
}
```